# Tomcat9 stop at this step without any errors and warnings

Tags: tomcat

```
04-Sep-2017 00:12:47.806 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M26
04-Sep-2017 00:12:47.837 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Aug 2 2017 20:29:05 UTC
04-Sep-2017 00:12:47.837 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         9.0.0.0
04-Sep-2017 00:12:47.837 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
04-Sep-2017 00:12:47.837 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
04-Sep-2017 00:12:47.837 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
04-Sep-2017 00:12:47.837 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre
04-Sep-2017 00:12:47.853 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_144-b01
04-Sep-2017 00:12:47.853 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
04-Sep-2017 00:12:47.853 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\tomcat
04-Sep-2017 00:12:47.853 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\tomcat
04-Sep-2017 00:12:47.853 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\tomcat\conf\logging.properties
04-Sep-2017 00:12:47.853 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
04-Sep-2017 00:12:47.853 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
04-Sep-2017 00:12:47.853 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
04-Sep-2017 00:12:47.853 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\tomcat
04-Sep-2017 00:12:47.868 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\tomcat
04-Sep-2017 00:12:47.868 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\tomcat\temp
04-Sep-2017 00:12:47.868 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.12] using APR version [1.5.2].
04-Sep-2017 00:12:47.884 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
04-Sep-2017 00:12:47.884 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
04-Sep-2017 00:12:49.025 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017]
04-Sep-2017 00:12:49.493 信息 [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

I want to launch my tomcat,but it always stops at this and doesn't continue,and doesn't show any errors and warnings.Then I download  Windows Service Installer version,it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it's because my new proxy software intercept `localhost` request.